# Implementing null safety on if statement?

Tags: flutter

I am updating my app to comply the null safety right now. Still new and trying to figure things out. However, I am stuck on the `if & else if` statement.

```
return Container(
  child: 
      if (_dashboardViewController.currentPage() == 'home') {
        return HomeView();
      } else if (_dashboardViewController.currentPage() == 'profile') {
        return ProfileView();
      } else if (_dashboardViewController.currentPage() == 'game') {
        return GameView();
      }
```

They are all `Container` widgets. But, I am receiving

`The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type. Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end.`

It worked before the null safety. I am quite lost where I can make this `null safety`. And, also, where can I put `?` to allow to have `null` value in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   if (_dashboardViewController.currentPage() == 'home') {
        return HomeView();
      } else if (_dashboardViewController.currentPage() == 'profile') {
        return ProfileView();
      } else if (_dashboardViewController.currentPage() == 'game') {
        return GameView();
      }
   else return Container() // it has to return something, can't return null/nothing
```